# Ubuntu 16.04 - wifi network list has disappeared

Tags: networking, wireless

I was using wireless internet with no issues, apart from last night where I kept having to enter the password to connect to a new network for the first time, even though the password was correct - but disabling wifi/networking and turning it on again sorted that.

I've gone to somebody else's house today and wanted to connect to their wifi, but it doesn't display on my list of available networks. In fact, nothing does. I've got my phone out to use as a mobile hotspot, I connected with no issues earlier on today but guess what? No wifi networks are displayed. You know, I've shied away from Linux for the last 15 years because there was always something basic that windows could do that it had trouble with, I took the plunge again after about five years and something as elementary as being able to connect to a bloody wifi network isn't even 100%...

Results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b732]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

PS: I went into Network on System Settings and it shows all 4 networks that I have connected to as "out of range", despite the fact that this computer is currently plugged in by ethernet cable to the wifi router, 6 inches from the laptop, and my phone, which is a wifi hotspot, is resting on the keyboard.

Edit: Here's the `wireless-info.txt` file, as David specified. Before I paste it though, I have to say - after I ran the third command to create the text file, Ubuntu said that I was now connected to the wi-fi in this house. I checked the drop down list and it was still showing nothing... but now it does. So, the problem is resolved but I don't know why, or how to prevent it again. Here's the file anyway:

Edit 25/4/16: Looks like I'm gonna try a different distro out. Since writing that I've had to reboot the PC twice to log into my wifi because the only wifi network my PC could see was one called "CG-PC_Network" unless I rebooted, despite turning networking/wi-fi on and off; I opened the laptop up and everything had frozen, I pressed CTRL-ALT-DEL after trying a few things and that made it work, but still, it shouldn't happen.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Apr 2016 18:13 BST +0100

Booted last: 24 Apr 2016 00:00 BST +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b732]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1179:f830]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13d3:5652 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0930:0222 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

toshiba_wmi            16384  0
rtl8723be              86016  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
sparse_keymap          16384  2 toshiba_wmi,toshiba_acpi
wmi                    20480  2 toshiba_wmi,toshiba_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5b58:e4ae:f0ba:cd35/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:72187478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34833177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:104432559622 (104.4 GB)  TX bytes:6393239025 (6.3 GB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1428  Metric:1
          RX packets:422544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:307203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:487673816 (487.6 MB)  TX bytes:123877077 (123.8 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       755     1  0 Apr23 ?        00:00:26 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ef132c91-3cdf-4b51-b9c0-86d1a0cf420a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/18
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ef132c91-3cdf-4b51-b9c0-86d1a0cf420a | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.8/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             194.168.4.100
IP4.DNS[2]:                             194.168.8.100
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        time_offset = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       expiry = 1461587296
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.8
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       domain_name_servers = 194.168.4.100 194.168.8.100
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       default_ip_ttl = 64
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5b58:e4ae:f0ba:cd35/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-21-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1428
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/virginmedia9968373]] (600 root)
[connection] id=virginmedia9968373 | type=wifi | permissions=user:tom:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=virginmedia9968373
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SKY47385]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SKY47385 | type=wifi | permissions=user:tom:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SKY47385
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Mobile Hotspot 2114]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Mobile Hotspot 2114 | type=wifi | permissions=user:tom:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Mobile Hotspot 2114
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MY WIFI 9446]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MY WIFI 9446 | type=wifi | permissions=user:tom:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MY WIFI 9446
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp1s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp1s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'virginmedia9968373' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-8 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"virginmedia9968373"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000b49de8a628
                    Extra: Last beacon: 28ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'SKYF7C67' [AC2]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SKYF7C67"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004437848d584
                    Extra: Last beacon: 416ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'NETGEAR' [AC3]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000004d4c64149
                    Extra: Last beacon: 164ms ago

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     935DB8E91ADCC9A3C200D60
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     AC6426E73F4CB059EE7332C
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     CCAF123FC0D21AE93AD5A6F
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     251B17ACC83990EE9A63C56
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     A882F4FE63500846E1C859E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     00D8DA6D3B739DDD31FFF50
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[27047.210642] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[27047.382872] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[27049.973753] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[27050.675455] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[27050.846948] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[27050.847033] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[27050.909408] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready (repeated 7 times)
[27247.514743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[27247.695344] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[27247.695438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[27247.750721] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[27362.775802] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[27362.775831] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[27962.993744] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready (repeated 6 times)
[44488.343333] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'virginmedia9968373' [AC1]>
[44488.951041] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'virginmedia9968373' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[44488.956108] wlp1s0: authenticated
[44488.957721] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'virginmedia9968373' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[44488.962561] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'virginmedia9968373' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=7)
[44488.963781] wlp1s0: associated
[44488.963807] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster - done

Comment: Network manager saw three access points in your areas at the time and associated with one of them earlier according to the system log excerpt. This may be what you describe as “Ubuntu said that I was now connected to the wi-fi in this house”. Maybe try again so this doesn't contort the diagnosis. Pilot6's suggestion is definitely worth a try. It would be helpful if you reported back with your findings about it.